# Avoid re-rendering a component which contains children props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

How to avoid re-rendering a component which is having **children props**. `React.memo` seems to be working only on regular props

```
const FormGroup = ({
  children
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default React.memo(FormGroup)
```

Answer (score 2):

`React.memo` takes a second argument which lets you control how and which props are compared.

```
function FormGroup(props) {
  /* render using props */
}
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
  return true;
}
export default React.memo(FormGroup, areEqual);
```

Note from [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

React.memo and React.PureComponent both cannot optimize defaultly if children prop is passed. That is because on each re-render of parent a new instance of Children prop is created and hence the reference is lost.

This is explained in details in [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8669)

Also as Dan Abramov mentioned in one of the comments within the the github link

You can choose to implement a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` for React.Component or an `areEqual` for React.memo. However doing this may often be an overhead and not necessarily be more beneficial than a render itself

Also render is cheap and fast and it okay to have a re-render for a simple component